# How to detect elbows and knees in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have these randomly generated data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(42)
y1 = np.random.randint(5,10,5)
y2 = np.random.randint(15,20,5)
y3 = np.random.randint(5,10,5)

y = np.append(y1 , y2)
y = np.append(y , y3)
y_cum = y.cumsum()

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'x': range(len(y)), 'y_cum': y_cum, 'y': y})
```

if we plot these data we can see an "elbow" (at 4 in the x-axis) and a "knee" (at 9 in the x-axis)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(df_test['x'], df_test['y_cum'])
```

I am using `from kneed import KneeLocator` to detect them.

I use the following code to detect the elbow:

```
kneedle = KneeLocator(df_test['x'], df_test['y'], curve='convex', direction='increasing', online=False, S=1)
elbow_point = kneedle.elbow
elbow_point
```

and the following code to detect the knee:

```
kneedle = KneeLocator(df_test['x'], df_test['y'], curve='concave', direction='increasing', online=False, S=1)
elbow_point = kneedle.elbow
elbow_point
```

The first one gives as output `13` and the second gives as output `1`, which are not the correct values

I am a bit lost why these values pop up. I have looked into the [source code](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed/blob/master/kneed/knee_locator.py) but I couldnt figure it out.

Any ideas ?

Comment: In my limited experience, `kneed` cannot handle noise well. But then again, which signal detection algorithms can?

Comment: If you change `online=True`, it finds the knee at 9. But, overall, this seems like a bug attributed to the normalization/transformation step in the algorithm. If you create an [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/arvkevi/kneed/issues), I will take a look when I get a chance. There is a new, [interactive dashboard](https://share.streamlit.io/arvkevi/ikneed/main/ikneed.py), where you can paste your data and tune the parameters on the fly. You might find it helpful for selecting the appropriate values for the parameters.

Comment: @Kevin Done. I very much appreciate your work